# Why all dataframe columns not appear ic csv while using pandas

Tags: pandas

When i write a code in vsc to print a dataframe in pandas some columns in the middle not appear

I tried to change the setting in vsc to make all columns appear but useless, some the columns in the middle disapeared

[screen shot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE02O.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please post the dataframe text from the image. You can [edit] it into your post and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). [We normally try to avoid pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), but this one might be useful for context, so it's fine. BTW, if you want more tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For display all columns u can use. None value means unlimited. You can change according what u want.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

And for display all rows

```
pd.set_option("max_rows", None)
```

For more features about set_option u can take look pandas doc. Here is link for set_option https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html